# get Header in excel file

Tags: python, excel, xlsx, xls, xlrd

My excel data looks like this:

```
    A    B    C
1   RAM  53.44  576
2   MOHAN  74.34  345
3   KISHAN  76.65  285
```

How can I extract headers contents from spreadsheets?

Comment: I edited my solution now it conforms to your file format

Comment: In Excel and Google Sheets, the column heading or column header is the gray-colored row containing the letters (A, B, C, etc.) used to identify each column in the worksheet. The column header is located above row 1 in the worksheet. What you ask is obviously not what you want. Please refine your question.

Comment: You need to conform to some kind of file format, it is not possible to detect if a row contain headers or is it just a row of string data. The solution I posted is correct, it does exactly what you want for the provided sample. If the row placement can change you can store the value for `skiprows` in a cell read it and then pass it to `pd.excel_read()`

Comment: i have one solution detect any bold format because all headers are in always bold format in my case @mrangry777

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#static code if header at 0,0 position
import xlrd 

loc = ("path of file") 

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc) 
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0) 

# For row 0 and column 0 
sheet.cell_value(0, 0) 

for i in range(sheet.ncols): 
    print(sheet.cell_value(0, i))
```

Comment: How this solves the problem in question? And is better than solution given by me?

Answer (score 9):

Your question is really unclear. However you can use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) library to read file excel format.

```
import pandas as pd
print(pd.read_excel('file.xlsx').columns)
```

Call to `.columns` list the headers of all the columns

Output example:

`Index(['id', 'email','server','profession'], dtype='object')`

**EDIT:**
Ok now I see you have very odd first to rows which do not comply with pandas data structure. The simplest solution is to skip the first two rows. And then import it into panadas `DataFrame`

use `skiprows` to skip first n rows. In your case 2

```
import pandas as pd
print(pd.read_excel('file.xlsx',skiprows=2).columns)
```

Comment: i need only headers no data see the excel image how i can identify headers in this excel file @mrangry7777

Comment: call to `columns` gives you the name of the headers it does not fetch any data. My example comes from a file with 4 columns: id,email,server,profession. No data was fetched only the headers

Comment: @mrangry7777 it's not proper solution suppose headers start from 15th row how you can predict that without skip-rows?

Answer (score 0):

Check out Pandas. It's a lot better than Xlrd and uses less code.

You should be able to get it's index, regardless of whether or not it's a header.

From memory think you have to use `df.head()` once you've created your dataframe.

Comment: You answer is incorrect head() lists the first rows of the data set

Comment: You're right, perhaps they need to tell `parse` to skip some rows?